# Given the function g(x). Determine $g^n(x)$ in terms of $n$. Next, find the value of $g^n(x)$.

Tags: functions

Help me.

Given that the function $g(x)=\frac{x+1}{x-1}$

Determine the function $g^n(x)$ such that $n$ is a positive integer. Next, find the value of $g^{37}(x)$.

Comment: Hint: Find $g^n(x)$ then substitute $n = 37$.

Comment: Is $g^2(x) = g(g(x))$?  Or is it $$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dg}{dx}?$$

Comment: $g^2(x)=g(g(x))$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
g(x) = \frac{x+1}{x-1} = \frac{(x-1) + 2}{x-1} = 1 + \frac{2}{x-1} & \Rightarrow g'(x) = -\frac{2}{(x-1)^{2}}\\\\
& \Rightarrow g''(x) = \frac{2\times 2}{(x-1)^{3}}\\\\
& \Rightarrow g'''(x) = -\frac{2\times 2\times 3}{(x-1)^{4}}\\\\
& \Rightarrow g^{(4)}(x) = \frac{2\times 2\times 3\times 4}{(x-1)^{5}}
\end{align*}

Thus it can be proven by induction that
\begin{align*}
g^{(n)}(x) = (-1)^{n}\times\frac{2\times n!}{(x-1)^{n+1}}
\end{align*}

I am sure you can take it from here.

**EDIT**

Based on the same expression as above, we have that
\begin{align*}
g^{2}(x) = 1 + \frac{2}{1 + \frac{2}{x-1} - 1} = x \Rightarrow g^{3}(x) = g(x) = 1 + \frac{2}{x-1} \Rightarrow g^{4}(x) = g^{2}(x) = x \Rightarrow \ldots
\end{align*}

Based on such pattern, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
g^{n}(x) =
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle 1 + \frac{2}{x - 1} &\text{when}\,\,n = 2k-1\\\\
x &\text{when}\,\,n = 2k
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
for $\mathbb{N}\ni k\geq 1$.

Comment: Lol $~~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: Another answers?

Comment: $\frac{n+1}{n-1}=1 + \frac{\textbf{2}}{n-1}$?

Comment: I have edited my response in order to answer properly the question

Comment: Another solution? Pls

Comment: I Don't understand.

Comment: Take $n = 37$, which is odd. Consequently, $g^{37}(x) = g(x)$.

Comment: $g^2(x)=g(g(x))$ . $g^{37}(x)=$ g(g(g(g(g(g(g(g(g(....g(x))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))) ??

Comment: $g(x) = g(g^{2}(x)) = ... = g(g^{36}(x)) = g^{37}(x)$